# Windows Fax and Scan Report

Tags: vb.net

I'm using FAXCOMEXLib to broadcast faxes to my clients in bulk amounts. I've successfully managed to send all the faxes, however there is an issue sometimes in that the fax was not sent for whatever reason.

Is there a way to track which faxes are not sent in an after-fax report or something?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to this is simply to use the Windows Fax and Scan app, and view the Outbox. It holds all the information. Gonna close this now.